# count/rank a list in python base on occurance

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, count

I'd like to write this script in python.
I have a dataset of a bunch of credit card transactions. That include the date, account number, the amount (either a purchase or a credit/refund)
Data will look like this

```
Acct Number --- Amount
4445 --- $20
4445 --- $30
4445 --- $30
7555 --- $50
7555 --- $50
7555 --- $60
```

First, I'd like combine the account number with the amount,something like this

```
4445 | 20
4445 | 30
4445 | 30

7555 | 50
7555 | 50
7555 | 60
```

Then, I will count each tuples within the whole list based on the occurance of them. For example:

```
4445 | 20 | 1
4445 | 30 | 1
4445 | 30 | 2

7555 | 50 | 1
7555 | 50 | 2
7555 | 60 | 1
```

As you can see, the tuple ( 4445 | 20 ) appears only once, I want to count as 1
The tuple ( 4445 | 30 ) appears twice, so I want to count the first tuple as 1 and the second as 2.

Same, tuple (7555 | 50) appears twice, the first appearance will count as 1, next as 2, 
and the (7555 | 60) only shows once, so I count as 1.

I'm trying several ways but it didn't give me what I want.
Really appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following uses `itertools.groupby`, which requires the input to be sorted, and `enumerate` that gives us the indexes of items in an iterable. We treat each row as a string and then append the count after it.

```
L = [["4445 | 20","4445 | 30","4445 | 30"],
     ["7555 | 50","7555 | 50","7555 | 60"]]

from itertools import groupby

R = [[ r + ' | ' + str(i+1) 
     for h,g in groupby(A) 
     for i,r in enumerate(g)] for A in L]

for A in R:
    for r in A:
        print r
    print
```

This results in:

```
4445 | 20 | 1
4445 | 30 | 1
4445 | 30 | 2

7555 | 50 | 1
7555 | 50 | 2
7555 | 60 | 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import Counter

lines = list()

with open("data.text", 'r', encoding="utf-8") as data:
    for line in data[1:]:
        lines.append(line.split(" --- $"))

ct = Counter(lines)

for item in ct:

    print(' | '.join([*item, str(ct[item])]))
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use a nested dict where the key is `account` and key is another dict with `amount` as `key` and appearances as the value.

```
from collections import defaultdict
data_dict = defaultdict(dict)
with open(file,r):
  for line in file:
    acc.amount = line.split(',')#assuming the data is split based on a comma
    data_dict[acc][amount] = data_dict[acc].get(amount,0)+1
#print it like so
for key in data_dict:
  for am in data_dict[key]:
    print(key,data_dict[key],data_dict[key][am])
```

Comment: This is how one used to have to write this stuff. Now there are `defaultdict` and `Counter` in the `collections` module that simplify things greatly (no need to test for existence of a key before updating its value, for instance).

Comment: @PaulMcG about to edit my answer with them, thank you!

Comment: @PaulMcG please suggest any improvements in my edit :)

Comment: Untested, but if you change to `data_dict = defaultdict(Counter)`, then your update statement should simply become `data_dict[acc][amount] += 1` and everything else should be unchanged.